# CSS: Links inside columns move when clicked

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with the CSS on a wiki engine I coded.  Under the tag category pages, a list of links to pages bearing a particular tag is displayed under a two-column div.  However, I am having an issue with the column.

Whenever I click a link in the second column, a dotted-line border appears around the link, affecting its height and thereby affecting the height of the column, causing it to get shifted to a higher or lower position.

This results in the click to the link failing to register, and it can take a few attempts to actually get the link to open.

I cannot get the dotted-line border to disappear.  I have set the following for active links:

```
a:active{
    text-decoration:none;
    border:0px none black;
}
```

However, that has not helped any.  The border still appears.

Here is a link to an affected page on my website: http://lordofmaelstrom.com/tags/cosmology
And a direct link to the website's CSS file: http://lordofmaelstrom.com/theme.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
a:active, a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help out! Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked out for you.

Comment: Aye, I just have to wait another minute before I'm allowed to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try applying the style to A and not just to the active link.

```
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```